# Patch a python object to add default to method kwargs

Tags: python

I want to patch some code that uses an object from an external module.

One method of this object is called all over the place, and I need to set a new default kwarg in all those calls.

Rather than add so much duplicate code, I thought it would be better to change the object method. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is called [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patch) and there is no "clean" version of it.

If you need to replace a method `bar` in a class `Foo`, use this code:

```
oldMethod = Foo.bar
def newMethod(self, **kwargs):
    ... fix kwargs as necessary ...
    oldMethod(self, **kwargs)
Foo.bar = newMethod
```

1. First, we save the old method handle in a variable
2. Then we define the new method as a function. The first argument has to be `self`, just as if this function was inside of a class.
3. To call the original method, we use `oldMethod(self, ...)`. This will take the method pointer, and call it with the instance as first argument. `self.oldMethod()` doesn't work since we're not in a `class` context (I think).
4. Lastly, we install the patched method in the class.

Related:

- http://mflerackers.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/modifying-python-classes-at-run-time/

Comment: Where does `self.oldMethod` get defined/set?

Comment: Wouldn't this be much neater as a decorator?

Comment: @sapi if you were able to modify the source. But, I doubt that's what the OP wants here because if that were the case, then the OP would have done that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a wrapper class which inherits from the object I needed to modify.

```
class Wrapper(Target):
    def method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['option'] = True
        return super(Wrapper, self).method(*args, **kwargs)

instance = Target()
instance.__class__ = Wrapper
```

Comment: why not just: `instance = Wrapper()`?

Comment: in my real situation, the instance is returned by a function from an external module that I don't want to edit. quite possibly there is a better way to do this though I know very little about classes.